# Configure NGINX Reverse Proxy in front of Apache Web Server

Tags: apache, ubuntu, nginx, websocket, ratchet

So I started using Ratchet (library to program and use a websocket server in PHP, http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world) to program a chat application on my website (on the web server itself).

I set it all up on my localhost and it all works. Now I wanna deploy it on my web server, which is an Apache Server. For this to work, I apparently need to configure a reverse proxy, ideally with NGINX, in front of my web server, because the websocket server cannot simply listen on the same port as my Apache server.

When searching for sources which explain how to configure a reverse proxy with NGINX in front of my Apache web server, search results / articles / tutorials always tell me how to configure a reverse proxy using NGINX on an Apache WebServer ON UBUNTU. I'm confused why Ubuntu always comes into play here; isn't it simply possible to configure an NGINX reverse proxy in front of my Apache web server, without the use of Ubuntu?

**UPDATE**

My server is a web server on a shared hosting basis, and I have no root access. So is it actually even possible to place a reverse proxy in front of my web server, given that I can't even change to which port my web server listens..?

To may describe in a better way what EXACTLY I want: A specific page of my website should load its content (html structure, representing a chat window) from the web server, but its chat functionality, present as PHP Ratchet script on the server-side, should work via a WebSocket connection. In other words, for this page, Web Server and WebSocket connections should work simultaneously, while I have only one Apache server, on a shared hosting basis, with no root access, on which both the chat application programmed in Ratchet and the website's HTML page are present (at least on my localhost, this worked very nicely). Is that even possible to deploy given my hosting conditions, or do I need to switch to another hosting type?

Also, please don't consider this question to be specific to nginx. According to the documentation in Ratchet, the solutions I have are:

1. Run web site and WebSocket server on the same machine using port 8080 for WebSockets and take the chance client proxies won't block traffic
2. Run WebSocket server on its own server on port 80 under a subdomain (sock.example.com)
3. Put a reverse proxy (Nginx, HAProxy, Varnish) in front of your web server and WebSocket server

I also figured out (github)

4. Use the mod_proxy_wstunnels extension available for Apache

I'm more than happy to know about any of the four or other recommended solution, even if this wouldn't include nginx.

Comment: Please provide more information about this "Apache Server". Is a mutualized solution ? A VPS ? What distribution ? Whom is the hosting provider ?

Comment: Note: this question is not suited to Stack Overflow and will be deleted shortly (I assume). You should ask it over at serverfault.com
Make sure to provide as much information about your hosting solution

Comment: upated information under "UPDATE", please check.

Comment: Updated my answer. Yet, I must insist, the lads over at serverfault.com will definetly be far more knowledgeable than me (as serverfault.com is specifically focused on this kind of problems). You should try over there instead.

Also, your question has already been voted to close twice so you might want to go to serverfault.com

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for your help anyway!

Comment: On the other side, I must say that I wanted to ask the question in this forum because it concerns Ratchet may more specifically than I thought, as well as nginx, etc., and these may be more programmatically focused aspects than server-aspects. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help, I didn't know about that forum.

Comment: Well, in this question you specifically ask about NGNIX, which is not suited to stack overflow.

If you try to setup your projet without NGINX and encountered an error that you believe might be fixed in a way other than setting up an NGINX (thought code, precisely), you are welcome to *start a new thread* asking for help on this topic. 
If you elect to do so, make sure to read this post before actually posting.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

keep in mind, the better your question the more likely you are to receive a quick and good answer !

Comment: Thanks again for your feedback; please don't consider my request to be specific to nginx. I just learned how to use nginx now and would thus obviously prefer to use nginx now, but I'm open for any solutions which would make my plan work (see suggestions I found in my research above).

Comment: Have you tried the 4th option ? It seems to be the simplest but it requires that you have access to the apache config

Comment: Also, I don't think you mentioned it, what company are you using for hosting ?
Like, OVH, Cloudflare, Azure, AWS, whatever ?

Comment: I posted a new question about this module (4th option) on serverfault indeed, it seems to be my last chance before switching to a dedicated host contract. I however also think that it requires access to apache's config file, which I don't have in my shared hosting on GoDaddy. Nevertheless, GoDaddy actually recommended that extension to me, which confuses me a lot; no clue how to do that without root access at the moment.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I can help you much more than that ... I have never used GoDaddy as a host, haven't used PHP in about 5 years and never used websockets or any library in PHP ... :-/ 
Good luck !

Comment: Dude, in addition to what u said, it also helped me a lot being forwarded to serverfault.com. Atfer a few talks there and other talks with my host, I now finally know definitely which structure to build up on my server / app-side, so even if you think you didn't help a lot, for me it helped a lot, so thanks a lot again!

Comment: My pleasure ! Glad I could help then :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the UPDATE section:
We'll assume that you can't place a reverse proxy in front of your hosted solution *within the hosting solution itself*. That seems very unlikely.

My best bet would be to setup a reverse proxy on a dedicated VPS and pass all your trafic through this but this setup is far more convoluted than you probably require.

---

From the line "[...] on my web server, which is an Apache Server." I guess you are using a mutualized hosting solution. In which case, it'll depend heavily on which specific host you are using. In your CPannel try to look for "reverse proxy"/"proxy"/"socket"/"web socket" parameters.

If you're hosting on VPS and your distribution of linux of the "family" as ubuntu, follow a tutorial and it might just work. Otherwise, look for a tutorial specific to your distribution (or OS if you're not on linux).

Comment: Yes, as updated now only above (sorry for that), it's a shared hosting account, wich doesn't allow for any root access. Not even CPanel is configured, only wordpress, and some kind of hosting dashboard, where I cannot find anything.
But without root access, is it even possible? Or am I obliged to force to switch to dedicated and / or VPS hosting for my purpose?

Comment: As commented above, this is not my aread of expertise. Yet, I don't know of any CPannel wordpress host allowing for a reverse proxy configuration of any kind. So I would personally go for a VPS solution.

But I must insist, serverfault.com will probably provide you with a *definitive* answer and maybe a solution simpler than a VPS regarding this problem.